# UIView not visible in UITableView Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Why won't my UIView (created below) show up in the `UITableViewHeader` that I try to add it to?

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 20, 20, 400, 400)];
searchBar = (UISearchBar *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[view addSubview:searchBar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:.35];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1.0);
label.text = @"188 People";
label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[view addSubview:label];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Comment: are you adding your UIView to the ViewController's main view?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:view]; at the end...

Comment: @lakesh Look at the last line of the posted code.

Comment: can you do [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:view]; ??

Comment: If I add this code to `viewDidLoad` in my app it adds a huge red header. So this code actually works. In which method are you calling this code? Check if self.tableView is not nil: add `NSAssert(self.tableView, @"Must have a table view");` above this code snippet. If it crashes self.tableView is nil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 20, 20, 400, 400)];
    searchBar = (UISearchBar *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view addSubview:searchBar];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:.35];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1.0);
    label.text = @"188 People";
    label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;//Please note the header will look the same for each section. You can add a switch or if/else to augment this
}
```

-As a side note, if you're planning on using the label here to set the text for the header, I suggest looking into the following methods:

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Comment: Read the original code. The question is about the header view for the table, not for a section header.

Comment: Section header or table header, whatever, this has stopped working on iOS7... does anyone know any solution?